# Wordpress - creating multiple widgets with several fields

Tags: widget, wordpress

I am attempting to create some custom widgets.

I have created one, which only needed a different title field. However I am now stuck when trying to create a widget which allows me to have multiple fields. I need the following fields for the widget:

- Title
- Introduction text
- Main text
- Email address

I want the widget form to allow the user to update the fields above with text. I then want to output the text they have written in my sidebar widget.

I have the following code which is for the previous widget I made (with no extra fields other than title)

```
class registercv_widget extends WP_Widget {

        function __construct() {
            parent::__construct(
                'registercv_widget',
                __('Register CV Widget', 'registercv_widget_domain'),
                array( 'description' => __( 'Provides a "Register CV" button which launches a pop-up', 'registercv_widget_domain' ), )
            );
        }

        public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
            $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] );
            echo $args['before_widget'];
            echo '<div class="widget-wrapper">';
            if ( ! empty( $title ) )
                echo $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title'];

    // This is where you run the code and display the output
            echo __( '<div class="register-button"><span><div class="button white">Send your CV</div></span></div>', 'registercv_widget_domain' );
            echo '</div>';
            echo $args['after_widget'];
        }

    // Widget Backend
        public function form( $instance ) {
            if ( isset( $instance[ 'title' ] ) ) {
                $title = $instance[ 'title' ];
            }
            else {
                $title = __( 'Register as a candidate', 'registercv_widget_domain' );
            }
    // Widget admin form
            ?>
            <p>
                <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:' ); ?></label>
                <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>" />
            </p>
        <?php
        }

    // Updating widget replacing old instances with new
        public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
            $instance = array();
            $instance['title'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['title'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] ) : '';
            return $instance;
        }
    }

    function registercv_load_widget() {
        register_widget( 'registercv_widget' );
    }
    add_action( 'widgets_init', 'registercv_load_widget' );
```

This works fine but **how can I add extra fields to this?**

I have attempted copying all instances of `$title` and making them again but with `$text_one` but I do not understand how this field is being registered. Can anybody help?

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this?  I have a similar question in regards to the form I thought about asking but if you have found a solution I would just upvote your Q&A.

Comment: @Darth_Vader just added my answer for you, hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution.

I started with the code above and was able to create multiple fields as such:

```
echo $args['before_widget'];
        echo '<div class="widget-wrapper">';
        if ( ! empty( $title ) )
            echo $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title'];
        if ( ! empty( $text_two ) )
            echo '<p>' . $text_two . '</p>';
        if ( ! empty( $link_text ) )
            echo '<p><a href="/employers/executives">' . $link_text . '</a><i class="fa fa-play"></i></p>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo $args['after_widget'];
```

The above example makes use of `$text_two` and `$link_text` variables which can be set through the widget screen with use of the following:

```
public function form( $instance ) {
        if ( isset( $instance[ 'title' ] ) ) {
            $title = $instance[ 'title' ];
        }
        else {
            $title = __( 'Executive Search', 'executive_widget_domain' );
        }

        if ( isset( $instance[ 'text_two' ] ) ) {
            $text_two = $instance[ 'text_two' ];
        }
        else {
            $text_two = __( 'Systematic searching to map the right talent for Director level roles using the best possible sector intelligence.', 'executive_widget_domain' );
        }

        if ( isset( $instance[ 'link_text' ] ) ) {
            $link_text = $instance[ 'link_text' ];
        }
        else {
            $link_text = __( 'Visit Executive Search', 'executive_widget_domain' );
        }
        // Widget admin form
        ?>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:' ); ?></label>
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>" />
            <br /><br />
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'text_two' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Main text:' ); ?></label>
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'text_two' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'text_two' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $text_two ); ?>" />
            <br /><br />
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'link_text' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Link text' ); ?></label>
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'link_text' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'link_text' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $link_text ); ?>" />
        </p>
    <?php
    }
```

## Entire code snippet here which can be popped right into your project. http://pastebin.com/X7wXmcds

Placing the above code in your `functions.php` will give you a widget called `Executive Search. It has three fields:`title`,`text_two`(a simple text string) and`link text`. So those are the three fields the user can add.